# Booting FreeBSD alongside Linux

Tags: linux, zfs, bsd, ufs

I want to install FreeBSD alongside my Debian, Arch and Kali installs, but I'm having problem creating a bootable USB. I followed the instructions given in the BSD handbook, but my PC doesn't recognise the USB during boot process. I tried

```
$ chainloader (hd0)/boot/boot1.efi
$ boot
```

at the  grub prompt but it gave an error which says something like 'zfs couldn't find pool;ufs couldn't find slice; can not load loader.efi;'

`loader.efi` is also in the `(hd0)/boot` directory. Do I need to format the USB drive as USB or ZFS prior to image burning, or do I need to format the partitions on which I'm going to install BSD as UFS or ZFS?

My laptop is an HP-15ac650tu.
These are the two images I used, the result was same both times:

ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/11.0/FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso.xz

ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/11.0/FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso.xz

NOTE: I have read the other threads with similar names, and they do not mention the error I'm getting.

Comment: You said you are using *loader.efi*.  Does the computer you are using have EFI firmware?  What computer do you have?

Comment: Yes, my hd has gpt and legacy support is disabled. Li

Comment: loader.efi is a file in the boot directory of freebsd iso I have. My laptop is hp-15ac650tu.

Comment: Can you add the link to the FreeBSD.iso used?

Comment: There is a memstick version - see my answer on how to create the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

First, off, doing a quick check of the [User Guide](http://bit.ly/2dCPCfB), it appears that your computer uses a BIOS, not EFI.

That said, you are probably using the wrong FreeBSD image to begin with.  Download using your version of Linux, either of the following images ***specific for creating a USB installer***

- [FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.3/FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img)
- [FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/11.0/FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img)

Once you have the image, use `dd` to write the image to the USB drive

To do this, you will need to know the device identifier of the USB drive (i.e. /dev/disk0, /dev/disk1, etc.)

Once you know this, execute this command:

`dd if=FreeBSD-VERSION-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/diskX bs=1M`

Where *VERSION* is the version of FreeBSD that is downloaded and *X* is the device number of your USB drive.

You should be able to boot from the USB after this.